# Is here a way to restart from the beginning the <animate> in a SVG element?

Tags: svg, jquery-animate, rect

Just need to know how we can restart the  sequence of the  elements that are inside a `<svg>`.  Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/nya13/4hzkno1f/3/

```
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin: auto; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; display: block; shape-rendering: auto;" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
      <circle cx="50" cy="23" r="13" fill="#e15b64">
        <animate attributeName="cy" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.45 0 0.9 0.55;0 0.45 0.55 0.9" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="23;77;23"></animate>
      </circle>
    </svg>
    <button onclick="RestartAnimate();">Restart Animate</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    function RestartAnimate() {
        // Do something...
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: set repeatCount to something > 1 or indefinite

Comment: hmmm, that did not work.  Maybe I should have mentioned that repeatCount was already set to "indefinite" initially.  Even if it wasn't, that did not seem to work.  Setting each `<animate>`'s repeatCount to "0" and then to "indefinite" did not affect its animation sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<button onclick="RestartAnimate();">` You must remove the semicolon

Assign Animation Identifier `<animate id="an"`

Assign `begin="indefinite"`

In the example below, the cycle repeats three times after pressing the button <kbd>Restart Animate</kbd>

```html
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin: auto; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; display: block; shape-rendering: auto;" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
      <circle cx="50" cy="23" r="13" fill="#e15b64">
        <animate id="an" attributeName="cy" dur="1s" repeatCount="3"  begin="indefinite" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.45 0 0.9 0.55;0 0.45 0.55 0.9" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="23;77;23"></animate>
      </circle>
    </svg>
    <button onclick="RestartAnimate()">Restart Animate</button>
  </body>
  <script> 
   var animation = document.getElementById("an")
    function RestartAnimate() {
        animation.beginElement();
}
  </script>
</html>
```